# WordPress template for Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wordpress, orchardcms

I am looking for a charity template to help my friend to make a website for a non-profit organization.
But I don't know how to program in PHP, I already know ASP.Net MVC 3 and C#.

I found out a nice template: http://osc4.template-help.com/wordpress_30418/
but is just for wordpress, does anybody know if is possible to adapt it to use with ASP.Net MVC, or Orchard?

Best regards,
Tito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would require a lot of work. You should be able to strip away the php and fill in the appropriate Orchard code. Your first goal could be to do remove the PHP. Then mock in the HTML to get it to look right then change it to use Razor.  The top is flash.